# not able load log4j properties file in Java webstart - Java 7u45

Tags: java, properties, java-web-start, jnlp

I am not able to load log4j property file after updating java 7u45. 
In my project log4j property file location setting via jnlp 
with passing VM args like 

 <property name="log4j.configuration" value="/cfg/log.properties">.

After java update I came to know VM args need to be pre-pend with 'jnlp'. After changing this I am able to get all system properties. But my logger is not able to get this log.properties location because it is key is appended with 'jnlp'. I can add a logic to read the value and set 'log4j.configuration' in system properties. 

But I am looking an alternate option to avoid this code.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only other option is to sign the jnlp.